# Function editor can i use string-operators

Tags: qgis, qgis-custom-function

In the Function editor I'm trying to edit a string something like:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def testfunc2(value1, value2, feature, parent):
    s =trim(value1 + value2)
    return s
```

I get the error:

```
Eval Error:
global name 'trim' is not defined
```

Can I use functions like trim, concat etc. in the Function editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can.

The problem is, that there is no method `trim` available. But there is a method `strip()` available on every string. You probably want to do

```
s = value1 + value2 # Concat
s = s.strip() # Trim
```

In general, you need to import functions. So if you did not import the function `trim`, it will not be available.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I import functions like trim etc. I tried all the Qgis libraries like QGis.Utils.

Comment: Why do you think that there should be a function `trim` in QGIS? Normally, if it's not geo-specific, read the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/) or look for generic python modules and if you look for geo-specific stuff read the [pyqgis cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/)

Comment: I didn't but I hoped. In the QGis Expression dialog (2.12.3) you can use these functions for a regular expression. So I assumed they were also usable in the function editor which is also in the Expression Dialog.

Comment: Expression functions are not usable in the function editor. The function editor is pure python. But no reason to worry, python covers **way** more functionality than there are expression functions.

Comment: I found some good documented examples of python code in apps\python27\lib\string.py. Thank you for your time and quick response.